# Bartle's Dominated Convergence Theorem condition

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

The DCT is stated as follows in Bartle's text:

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of integrable functions which converges almost everywhere to a real-valued measurable function $f$. If there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n| \le g $ for all $n$, then $f$ is integrable and 
>   $$ \int f \, d \mu = \lim \int f_n \, d \mu .$$

I was wondering if we need the condition that it converges a.e. to a **"real-valued measurable function $f$"**. I believe we can replace it with conergence a.e. to a **"real-valued function."**

As each $f_n$ is integrable, by definition each $f_n$ is measurable. Hence, $f =  \lim f_n = \lim \inf f_n$ is measurable. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $f$ should be measurable up to a null set since you only have almost everywhere convergence.

See for instance the version of DCT in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), or the one in Folland's Real Analysis:

[image]